# Splash Screen with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, splash-screen

I want to implement a splash screen into my app. I already did this. But at the moment it just waits 3 seconds and then calls the MainActivity class. The problem with that is that i have data to load and with the current setup the user have to waits two times. I want a splash screen that loads all the data. I have a MainActivity class where everything happens and I have my SplashScreen class.

The method I want to be run in the background is in my MainClass. So basically I have my splash screen class like that

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

protected void onCancelled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

I also implemented but not copied the imports and packages, so that shouldn't be a problem. Now, if I understood correctly I need to write the task that should be done into the doInBackground method. So I basically have to call the method from my other activity class, right?

```
public MainActivity mA = new MainActivity();
```

and then in the method I would write `mA.parseXMLfromURL();`

And afterwards I would start an intent of the main class into the onPostExecute-method like this?

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void... params) {
    Intent mainClass = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainClass);

}
```

If more information is needed I will gladly elaborate further.

**UPDATES**

Well, after your comments I tried it a bit differently.

This is my oncreate method

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sv      = new ScrollView(this);
    layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(layout);
    setContentView(sv);     

    new SplashScreenActivity().execute("URL TO FILE");
}
```

And this is the SplashScreenActivity

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
public MainActivity mA = new MainActivity();

protected void onPostExecute(Void... params) {
}

protected void onCancelled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    mA.parseXMLfromURL(params);
    return null;
}
```

`}`

But this just returns a blank screen. However if I call the parseXMLfromURL in my main activity it works just fine.

@Raghunandan said in comments that I wrongly created the instance of the class. Would be glad if you could elaborate your answer.

**UPDATE NUMBER TWO**

Current SplashScreen-Code is the following:

package de.activevalue.T1000flies;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    new mTask().execute();
}

private class mTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    MainActivity mA = new MainActivity();
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        mA.parseXML();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void... params){
        Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }


}
```

}

With that code the app just stucks at the Splash-Screen. It seeems like there is a problem with my XML-Parsing. Here is the XML-Parsing-code. Note that it works without any problems, when I just start the main activity wihtout the splash screen

**UPDATE NUMBER THREE**

I just started to debug by making breakpoints line per line. It jumps out at this line

```
rankingDate [k]             = new TextView(this);
```

Rest of the code

```
for(int k = 0; k < metaList.getLength(); k++){

            Node metaNode = metaList.item(k);
            System.out.println(metaList.getLength());
            rankingDate [k]             = new TextView(this);
            rdate       [k]             = new TextView(this);
            numberOE    [k]             = new TextView(this);

            Element metaElement = (Element) metaNode;
            NodeList rankingDateList    = metaElement.getElementsByTagName("date");
            Element rankingDateElement  = (Element) rankingDateList.item(0);
            rankingDateList             = rankingDateElement.getChildNodes();
            rankingDate [k].setText("RankingDate: " + ((Node) rankingDateList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
            layout.addView(rankingDate[k]);

            xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "date");
            xmlSerializer.text(((Node) rankingDateList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
            xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "date");

        }
```

The system.out.println gives me 1. And k is 0. So why is it a Null Pointer Exception?

Comment: creating an instance of a activity class `MainActivity mA = new MainActivity()` ? If so its not right

Comment: You have data to load in MainActivity. There also have another AsyncTask. So user waits twice. isn't that your problem?

Comment: Hi, I updated it. See the bold **update** for the information. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

You should create new activity for SplashScreen --> SplashScreenActivity extends Activity, declare in manifest and than set layout ;

```
public SplashScreenActivity extends Activity{

 protected void onCreate(Bundle ...){
  super.onCreate(...);
  setContentView(...);
  new mTask().execute();
 }

 private class mTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void... params) {
   Intent mainClass = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainClass);
    finish();
}

 }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Did exactly what you said, but now it is stuck in the Splash Screen. I get no messages in the log cat or console. But well, it doesn't change the intent. I got no errors in the code. Copied your code and just added the call to the method in the `doInBackground`-method

Comment: @Musterknabe Did you also do the onPostExecute portion? The code you posted in the edit to your question doesn't include that. Post your exact code.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi - I updated the initial post. Please have a look at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Piggy-backing off nurisezgin's answer explaining how AsyncTasks work in android, you're almost there but need to get some other things out of the way.

First: In Android-world, you *never* initialize activities by calling their constructor. Activities are handled by the operating system, and you run them using `Intent`s.

That out of the way, you're very close to having your issue solved. You need to take whatever code is in the `parseXML` function of your `MainActivity` and put it either into your `SplashScreenActivity` and call it, or just put it directly in your `doInBackground` method.

Your `doInBackground` method should not be calling any outside activities.

Comment: Hey, but in the parseXML-Method I'm adding things to the layout of the MainActivity class. How do I handle this? I mean, I understand your point, but what do I do when wanting to change the layout of another class?

Comment: Any thing that requires the UI thread needs to be done on your `onPostExecute()`, if you give more specifics about what you're doing I can help you out more but for the generic case of downloading something from the internet and displaying it, I'd say don't do a splash screen and instead show a loading bar in your other activity, or save the data somewhere.

Comment: Hi, what exactly I'm doing is the following: 

The app starts and then gets data from XML via an URL. It then proceeds to read the data and save them to TextViews and display them via a forloop and using arrays. I wanted to implement a Splash-Screen so the user sees the logo and doesn't have to wait for the app wondering why it takes so long. But yeah, a progress bar instead of a splash screen would also work. But all the progress bar tutorials I found where also with asynchronous tasks and would then have the same problem. 

Because I think passing all the data to onPostExecute is too much.

Comment: You would have no problem with showing a progress dialog (or ProgressBar somewhere in a view) in the `onPreExecute` method of your AsyncTask, then hiding it and doing your UI operations on the `onPostExecute`

Comment: Hey, I think this is above my skills at the moment. Because I wouldn't know how to iterate the progress bar and also I still wouldn't know where to do all the tasks. 

Could I maybe do everything in one class and then when the task is finished instead of starting a new intent just switching layouts? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do your splash screen is to have it appear in front of your main activity that needs to load data using [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html).  The easiest way to go about this is to override the onPreExecute() method in AsyncTask.  The following is a simple example of a splash screen.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new SplashScreen(this).execute();
    }
}
```

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    Context ctxt;
    Dialog splash;

    public SplashScreen(Context ctxt)
    {
        this.ctxt = ctxt;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        splash = new Dialog(ctxt, R.style.full_screen);
        splash.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... ignore)
    {
        //Fetch stuff
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void ignore)
    {
        splash.dismiss();
    }
}
```

In your res/values/styles.xml file, you want to put the following xml for full screen.

```
<!-- Stuff that's already in here -->

<style name="full_screen" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<!-- Stuff that's already in here -->
```

This will give you a very basic splash screen (i.e., a blank screen that says nothing).  If you look into the Dialogs API, you can find other ways to customize it that allow you to use pictures instead of text as well as completely customize the layout of the Dialog.  Also look into [DialogFragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) if you want an even further customization.  The benefit of doing your splash screen this way is that you can retrieve all of your information and set it up in the onPostExecute() to your MainActivity without having to worry about transferring the data.

Hope this helps!  Good luck.

Comment: This is the best approach because it dismisses the dialog only after resources load and there is no need for artificial progress counter while loading resources, although I run the AsyncTask directly from the Main activity and load resources from there.  I don't believe there's a need to make a new SplashScreen.java for this. i.e. `new SplashScreen().execute();` called from `onCreate()` in `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried exactly the same in a project, but my approach was different. Maybe it`could solve your problem as well...

first, my `SplashScreen` was an overlay in the `MainActivity`

```
 //main-activtiy xml
 <RelativeLayout ...
     <RelativeLayout id="overlay" visible="true"... //filled parent and had a centered image
     <RelativeLayout id="mainActivity" visible="false"... //the application
```

- Application launched
- Start your `AsyncTask` or `Service` in your `onCreateMethod`
- if data is loaded, send `Notification` to your `MainActivity` and "swap your view" like

  ```
  public void functionCalledOnDataLoaded(){
     //do you init stuff

    ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.overlay)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainActivity)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you only create MainActivity. The Splash is just a frame layout of main.xml, and will be setVisibility(View.GONE) after certain time.

Using this method, you have only 1 activity. Thus, it's easier to handle load data from network without interrupt.

Comment: I'm fairly new to async-tasks so I just followed a tutorial. If you could elaborate with a tutorial it would be really helpful